# Pandas merge method returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have two dataframes with the following info:

```
>>> ratings.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id            5 non-null int64
movie_id      5 non-null object
rating        5 non-null object
account_id    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes

>> movies.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 296 entries, 0 to 295
Data columns (total 9 columns):
id              296 non-null int64
description     296 non-null object
genre           296 non-null object
imdb_url        296 non-null object
img_url         296 non-null object
title           296 non-null object
users_rating    296 non-null object
year            296 non-null object
movie_id        296 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 20.9+ KB
```

Inspite of the common columns having the same data types, it shows:

```
>>> pd.merge(ratings,movies)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, movie_id, rating, account_id, description, genre, 
imdb_url, img_url, title, users_rating, year]
Index: []
```

The previous answers on stackoverflow suggest to check for the similarity of data types. However, since my data types are same, what is the solution for this error?

Comment: Not much we can do by staring at the dtypes, a better idea would be to share some of the data (considering there isn't much, that shouldn't be a problem for you). You can make up fake data to mimic your problem if you don't intend to share.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing and inner join using ['id', 'movie_id'] so if the resulting DF is empty then the combinations of id & movie_id in both dataframes don't have any match. Compare the distinct 'id' and 'movie_id' combinations in both dataframes

```
movies.groupby(['id', 'movie_id'])['id'].count()
ratings.groupby(['id', 'movie_id'])['id'].count()
```